# Convert YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MMM-YYYY in Python

Tags: python, date

I'm trying to convert a list of dates (strings) in the format 2023-01-19 into the format 19-Jan-2023. The code I currently have does not work:

```
date_list = ['2023-01-19', '2023-01-07', '2022-11-29']
new_date_list = []

for date in date_list:
   date_new_format = datetime.datetime(date, '%dd-%mmm-%yyyy')
   new_date_list.append(date_new_format)
```

Comment: Could you add `date_list` and explain what you mean with "it doesn't work" ?

Comment: your string is wrong https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

Comment: Something like `datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%b-%Y')`?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. The fact you have a list is inconsequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first create a `datetime` object with `strptime`, then you can use `strftime` to reformat it:

```
from datetime import datetime   

date_list = ['2023-01-19', '2023-01-07', '2022-11-29']    

for date in date_list:
    d = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    date_new_format = datetime.strftime(d, '%d-%b-%Y')
   
    print(date_new_format)
```